# New android studio project Cannot resolve symbol 'R'

Tags: android-studio

When I create a new project in Android Studio in any folder other than the folder I currently have projects in I get an error in `MainActivity.java`.  Below is the class...

```
package com.example.david.dynamicuifragments;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

I have created multiple projects, clean build, rebuild, sync project with gradle files.  Nothing fixes is this.  Please help

The error messages are:
Error:Failed to crunch file C:\Users\David\OneDrive\Development\MyAndroidStudio\AndroidDevelopersTraining\DynamicUIFragments\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\25.1.0\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_light.png into C:\Users\David\OneDrive\Development\MyAndroidStudio\AndroidDevelopersTraining\DynamicUIFragments\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_light.png

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Error: Failed to crunch file C:\Users\David\OneDrive\Development\MyAndroidStudio\AndroidDevelopersTraining\DynamicUIFragments\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\25.1.0\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_light.png into C:\Users\David\OneDrive\Development\MyAndroidStudio\AndroidDevelopersTraining\DynamicUIFragments\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_light.png

Comment: As @max suggested clean and build should work. If not place your cursor near `R.layout.activity_main` and hit `ALT + ENTER` this will import R class to your MainActivity

Comment: then check your sdk make sure everything is update

Comment: check your resource file name, it should  be defined in lower Case

Comment: I tried alt + enter, it did not have an import option.  This problem only happens when I try to create a new project in certain folders.  About 1 out of 20 projects I create works in these folders

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps:

1. close all other projects
2. go to Build -> clean : clean project
3. go to File -> invalidate Caches / Restart : invalidate caches

tell me if that works.

Comment: Nope, same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. In the build.gradle (project) file, find the dependencies section and try to update it to the latest beta version of the gradle tools.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-beta1'
```